# How to get content from [object HTMLDocument] in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch an HTML data (which I parsed from string because the javascript files linked to it doesn't work) from a url, then load the response into document. However, when I log the response in the console, I get the html content but it displays [object HTMLDocument] when I load the document.

Here is my code -

```js
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.text())
.then(data => {
    let parsedRes = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, "text/html")
    processData(parsedRes, url)
});

function processData(response, urlPath){
    console.log(response)
    document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = response;
    window.history.pushState({}, "", urlPath);
};
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response` is a document object, innerHTML expects a string. You could use the inner html of the `response` document...

```js
fetch(`data:text/html;,<html><head>\u003cscript src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js">\u003c/script><style>div {color:red;}</style></head><body>
<div>This is a red div</div>\u003cscript>$('div').append('<span style="color:green">(green span)</span>');\u003c/script></body></html>`)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(data => {
        let parsedRes = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, "text/html")
        setTimeout(function(){
            processData(parsedRes, 'url');
        }, 2500);
    });
    
    async function processData(response, urlPath){
        console.log(response)
        document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = response.querySelector("html").innerHTML;
        var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
            if (scripts[i].src){
                let script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = scripts[i].src;
                scripts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(script, scripts[i]);
                if (!scripts[i].async){
                    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        script.onload = ()=>resolve(true);
                        script.onerror = ()=>reject(false);
                    });
                }
            }
            else{
                let script = document.createElement('script');
                script.innerHTML = scripts[i].innerHTML;
                scripts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(script, scripts[i]);
                
            }
        }
        window.history.pushState({}, "", urlPath);
    };
```

```html
<div>This is the original div</div>
```

Comment: It worked but javascript files doesn't seem to load up. Have an idea how that could be solved?

Comment: Since innerHTML will not execute scripts you'll have to find them and execute them manually.